# How to implement list in llvm

Tags: c++, list, vector, stl, llvm

I'm creating my own compiler using LLVM as backend and in my language I want to give end user a list which operates like ArrayList in Java.
I can use ArrayType from llvm, but at creation time I have to specify size so there is a problem when I want to extend it (I can reallocate it ofc). Moreover I need to implement all the operations (inserting, removing etc.) manually.

I though that maybe I can use std::vector, but there is another problem - std::vector is a template class, so I have to specify type before compiling it to llvm bytecode. Is there some solution to specify that type dynamically?

What is the best method to implement such things in llvm?

I would be grateful for any solutions or tips.

Comment: std:vector<void*> x; Not a pretty solution as it will require casting all the time tho.

Comment: yeah, exactly. I came up with this solution before but casting everywhere is not what I want.

Comment: *In my compiler*... Are you creating your own compiler using LLVM as backend? If so then you need to design what the type does in your language and implement it (which is basically the implementation of `std::vector`). If you decide what it should do, what the interface should be and so on, you can ask a better question and get more precise answers.

Comment: I've updated the question. Interface of ArrayList in Java is simple, for now I need only it's basic functionality like insert, remove, size etc.

Comment: Have you already implemented a GC for your runtime? Give more information regarding your language semantics, otherwise your question does not make *any* sense at all.

Comment: @SK-logic no, not yet, but we plan to implement GC. Do you have any thoughts about it?

Comment: @remdezx, your implementation of the containers in your runtime must depend heavily on GC or on RAII semantics of your language, etc. So you really have to define semantics first and only then think of how to implement containers and such.

Comment: You write that you "thought about using std::vector". What do you mean by that? std::vector is a type from the C++ standard library, do you allow access to that type in your source language? How do you do that without template support?

Comment: @SK-logic, for now I just want to use basic structure like std::vector. Later on I will change it to something more efficient when copying fragments (something like Slices in Go-lang). Using external structure written in C++ like std::vector will give me more options to change it in the future.

Comment: @Oak, no I want to build a wrapper for std::vector (underlying structure can be changed later) and give end user only a wrapper.

Comment: The best option will be to not use void* in std::vector, but specify type, but unfortunately, as far as I know there is no way to do it in llvm api. I don't want to implement this structure all in llvm api because it's very hard to do it.

Comment: @remdezx, it does not matter how "basic" is it. Implementation depends heavily on your source language semantics and on the target runtime constraints. Please specify them explicitly if you want to get a useful answer.